# Definition of Riordan arrays

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I came across Riordan arrays and I am struggling with how the lower triangular array is created.

Take for example Pascal's triangle $P=\mathcal{R}(\frac{1}{1-t},\frac{t}{1-t})$. By definition, this pair creates the infinite, lower triangular array $d_{n,k}=[t^n]\frac{1}{1-t}(\frac{t}{1-t})^k$.

In the following steps, how do I handle $[t^n]$ and where does the binomial coefficient come from?

$d_{n,k}=[t^n]\frac{1}{1-t}(\frac{t}{1-t})^k=[t^{n-k}](1-t)^{-k-1}={n \choose k}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Recall that $$\frac{1}{(1-t)^k}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}t^n,$$
you can see this by expanding the product in the left hand side(the binomials in the right hand side count ordered partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts with parts $\geq 0$). 
$[t^n]$ just means to extract the coefficient of $t^n$ in the sum. For example, $[t^{\color{red}{2}}](1+t)^{\color{blue}{5}}=\binom{\color{blue}{5}}{\color{\red}{2}}$

Comment: I tried the same for the Catalan triangle but I failed at $d_{n,k}=[t^{n+1}](\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4t}}{2})^{k+1}=\frac{k+1}{n+1}{2n-k \choose n-k}$. Does someone get that step done?

Comment: You have to ask a different question. This one was answered.

Comment: @DFL This counts (partial) Dyck paths from $(0,0)$ to $(2n-k,k)$, whose number is $\binom{2n-k}{n-k}-\binom{2n-k}{n-k-1}$ (same bijective proof as for Dyck paths, "$\text{good} = \text{all} - \text{bad}$"). Or, you can try Lagrange inversion for $f=f(t)=C(t)-1$ that satisfies $f=t(f+1)^2$. You need $[t^{n+1}](t(f+1))^{k+1}=[t^{n-k}](f+1)^{k+1}$.